# ContextProvider doesn't mount when page refreshes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

Please see the full code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-countries-api-1ibwp).

I have two **Route** components for my countries api app-

```
<>
    <Header/>

    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <CountriesDataProvider>

                <Route path='/' exact component={HomeRoute} />
                <Route path='/detail/:countryName' component={DetailsRoute} />
                        
            </CountriesDataProvider>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</>
```

The `DetailsRoute` for each country shows up with all information perfectly when I click on a country on the `HomeRoute`. But when a direct *http* request is made or the `DetailsRoute` is refreshed, I see this error-

> /src/comps/Details/DetailsRoute.jsx
>
> Cannot read property 'borders' of undefined

It occurs on the line-

```
const promises = country[0].borders.map(fetchNeighborName);
```

`country[0]` is extracted from `countriesData` which seems to be `undefined`-

```
const {countriesData} = React.useContext(CountriesDataContext);
```

This is not an issue with `BrowserRouter`, because the `DetailsRoute` component does render but with missing info.

I don't kow what logical error is causing it to not work when a *direct url request* is sent to the `DetailsRoute` component? Please let me know the fix!

Comment: I think this is can be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453861/react-context-api-persist-data-on-page-refresh

Comment: @MehmetAliPeker I couldn't relate that to my problem. The issue I see when I set *breakpoints* in `CountriesDataContext` is that on reload, `componentDidMount` doesn't execute, and that's where I *fetch* the data for countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you reload the details page the response in `CountriesDataContext` hasn't come back yet, so `country` is empty. An easy way to solve the problem (and is generally good practice) is to add a check to make sure the data is there:

```
async function resolveBorders() {
  // Add a condition to make sure you have the data you expect.
  if (country.length) {
    const promises = country[0].borders.map(fetchNeighborName);
    setBorderCountries(await Promise.all(promises));
  }
}
```

Be sure to also add `country` to the effect's dependency array so that the effect runs again when the response comes back:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  async function resolveBorders() {
    ...
  }

  resolveBorders();
}, [borderCountries, country]); // <-- Add `country` here
```